# Extending Ant zipgroupfileset Type

Tags: ant

I am trying to implement an alternative Ant Type which works like zipgroupfileset but accepts a classpath-like string as input.

My problem is: even when downloading the source of apache ant, I cannot find any code or implementation-specific info about it, no typedef and no extended class. zipgroupfileset doesn't even seem to be properly documented. The main documentation about this Type seems to be this very short paragraph in the [Zip Task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html):

> zipgroupfileset
>
> A zipgroupfileset allows for multiple zip files to be merged into
>   the archive. Each file found in this fileset is added to the archive
>   the same way that zipfileset src files are added.
>
> zipgroupfileset is a fileset and supports all of its attributes and
>   nested elements.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Before you start trying to implement this for yourself, check whether the existing [`<archives>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#archives) resource collection will do what you need.

Comment: Not sure if this can help me: I need to evaluate a variable like `libs/a.jar;libs/b.jar;bin/c.jar` and include all its contents to a new jar using the `<jar>` task

Comment: Thanks Ian. This really seems to work as a solution for me.

Comment: There's lots of little gems like this in the resource collection abstraction, it's well worth getting your head around its intricacies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to evaluate a variable like `libs/a.jar;libs/b.jar;bin/c.jar` and include all its contents to a new jar using the `<jar>` task

You can do this using the [`<archives>` resource collection type](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#archives), available since Ant 1.8

```
<property name="jars.to.include" value="libs/a.jar;libs/b.jar;bin/c.jar" />

<jar destfile="dest.jar">
  <archives>
    <zips>
      <path path="${jars.to.include}" />
    </zips>
  </archives>
</jar>
```

---

Regarding `zipgroupfileset` itself:

> I cannot find any code or implementation-specific info about it, no typedef and no extended class.

There is no specific class that represents a `zipgroupfileset`, the logic is [embedded in the `zip` task implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/tags/ANT_192/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Zip.java?view=markup#l851).  The `Zip` task has a

```
public void addZipGroupFileset(FileSet set)
```

so the tag `<zipgroupfileset>` in the XML is treated as defining a normal `FileSet` - you could legally do

```
<fileset id="lib.jars" dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />

<jar destfile="dest.jar">
  <zipgroupfileset refid="lib.jars" />
</jar>
```

When the zip (or jar) task is executed, each "group" fileset is examined in turn and for each zip/jar file that the set contains a new `ZipFileSet` is generated to read from that file, and the contents of this generated `ZipFileSet` are added to the destination archive.

Comment: This indeed solved my specific problem. But I'll wait some days for accepting in the hope someone answers the question about the zipgroupfileset implementation. Thanks anyway

Comment: @DanielAlder there is no "implementation" of zipgroupfileset as such, the tag is implemented as a [special case inside the zip task](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/tags/ANT_192/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Zip.java?view=markup#l851) and is a normal fileset of zip/jar files that is "multiplied out" into a set of `<zipfileset src="..."/>` equivalents at runtime.

Comment: I saw that code. But this would mean that can also use zipfileset instead of zipgroupfileset? I cannot find any equals("zipgroupfileset") or similar..

Comment: @DanielAlder I've added a bit more detail to my answer, does this help explain things better?